# CROSS JOIN and UPDATE THIRD TABLE doesnt work

Tags: mysql, cross-join

I have the following issue. We have two tables that look like that :

```
[t1]
Ruler   ID1 S1  E1
**1     a   1   10**
1       b   17  24
1       c   20  24
1       d   21  24
*2      e   40  47*    

[t2]
Ruler   ID2 S2  E2
**1     a   7   15**
**1     b   8   16**
2       c   25  35
*2      d   41  50*

[t3]
Ruler   ID1 S1  E1  ID2  S2  E2  
**1     a    1  10    a   7  15
1       a    1  10    b   8  16**
*2      e   40   7    d  41  50*
```

- We have about 20 scales (here I just show scale 1 and 2)
- S1 (S2) AND E1(E2) Represent respectively start and end position on a scale
- L1(L2) is the length of each segment.  Segment from t1 can overlap
- segments from t2 and vice-versa Multiple segments can overlap each
  other

To select segments that overlap each other I need to do a CROSS JOIN of t1 and t2 and find what segment from t2 overlap those in t1 and then insert those into t3.

If I do table UPDATE that returns 0 match rows

```
UPDATE t3 CROSS JOIN (t1, t2) ON 
  ((t2.S2 BETWEEN t1.S1 AND t1.E1) OR (t2.E2 BETWEEN t1.S1 AND t1.E1))
SET t3.CHR1 = t1.CHR1, t3.ID1 = t1.ID1, t3.S1 = t1.S1, t3.E1 = t1.E1, t3.ID2 =
t2.ID2, t3.S2 = t2.S2, t3.E2 = t2.E2
WHERE t1.CHR1 = t2.CHR2;
```

If I do INSERT INTO t3 ( or a  INNER JOIN) that doesn't replace a CROSS JOIN. ...So I don't know what to do from here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe your query syntax is wrong.

update command syntax was 
`update <table> set x=(select query),... where ...`

And more over here it looks like you are joining T3 in the process and trying to update the temp table (`t3 CROSS JOIN (t1, t2)`) created in the join command.

Please check the syntax of cross join also.